# Establishing if a device is connected to a particular site

Tags: android, android-intent, inet

I am trying to establish if a device has a connection to a particular site.  If it does then it should start an intent, if it doesn't it should throw a toast.

It always seems to throw a toast though even if the device can see the site:-

```
public void GoToStation(View v)
{

    try {
        InetAddress ina = InetAddress.getByName("http://www.lisbury.co.uk");

        ina.isReachable(10000); {

                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomizedListViewStation.class);
                  startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        } 
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You need a data connection to view Safety Zones", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }    

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 InetAddress ina = InetAddress.getByName("www.lisbury.co.uk");
```

but isReachable doesn't really guarantee that a device can connect to a site - isReachable is using ICMP echo and TCP to port 7, both can be filtered out, yet the host is available, and vice versa - the host can be available, but web server is down

Comment: msh - is there a better way to do this then?  I want the intent to start if the device has connectivity.  Can I do this?

Comment: just send a GET request to the server and check whether it fails. Or better yet to conserve traffic send HEAD request.

Comment: MSH - sorry to ask but do you have an example of that request.  You would really help me out if you could help with my code

Comment: Also, isReachable returns a boolean.  He isn't checking the result, so it will always go into the intent launching part.  He needs to check if(ina.isReachable(10000)).  Also, this should never be done on the UI thread because it will block the thread it runs on for 10s.

Comment: You can check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346645/android-java-head-request-with-headers